# WCF Error regarding MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, wcf

I have been researching this error for a while now and I feel like this gets asked all the time...but I cannot seem to locate the issue.

I am getting the normal `MaxReceivedMessageSize` error:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded.
```

Am I missing something within my config on my service?

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="LifeEApplication.Services.RateService.RateServiceHost" behaviorConfiguration="RateService.RateServiceHostBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="LifeEApplication.Services.Contracts.RateServiceContract.IRateService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RateService.RateServiceHostBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="200"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicBinding" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             receiveTimeout="00:02:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:02:00">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>

      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="LocalBinding" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             receiveTimeout="00:02:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:02:00">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://integrationmdl.grangeinsurance.com/lifequote/LoggingServiceHost/DotNetLoggingServiceHost.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding" 
            name="BasicBinding" 
            contract="LifeEApplication.Services.Contracts.LoggingServiceContract.IDotNetLoggingService"/>

  <endpoint address="https://integrationmdl.grangeinsurance.com/lifequote/OracleTrimarkServiceHost/OracleTrimarkServiceHost.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding" 
            name="BasicBinding" 
            contract="LifeEApplication.Services.Contracts.OracleServiceContract.IOracleService"/>
</client>
```

My function works fine with small amount of data so I know that this is an issue with the size of the `MaxReceivedMessageSize`.  Everything that I try results in the same problem.

Something of note: When I debug the service with the `WCF Test Client`, the Config file that is shown has none of the max sizes that I am specifying within its config.

Comment: I have little experience with WCF config settings.  If I am debugging the service itself...why are the settings not being pulled from the webconfig for the service?  It looks like they are defaulting to something else.  Driving me crazy!

Comment: Are you getting this error on the server or the client side?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I am getting this error while debugging the service.  Manually debugging by right clicking the RateService project and choosing `Debug`, that is.

Comment: The config you are showing is the client config. You should increase the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` at the server. I assume you do have access to the server config?

Comment: @venerik Silly question...but where exactly is the server config?  I am debugging the service so I was assuming that the config within the service was the server config at that point.

Comment: Server is the web.config, client depends but usually app.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the client config needs to increase the message size. Right click on the config file, select "Edit WCF Config", then change the MaxReceivedMessageSize value.

Comment: That is already done (shown in the config from the question).  If I am debugging a service...where would the 'server config' be at?

Comment: Who is receiving the data?

Comment: If you are hosting in iis, then the service virtual folder has the config file

Comment: am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Are you sending data to the server? or is your client receiving data from the server?

Comment: It is hosted via IIS.  I explored the directory and opened the config within.  It seems to have the same config (meaning it has the same `bindings`, `behaviors`, and `maxReceivedMessageSize`, etc

Comment: Who ever is receiving the data is complaining it's too big. Either your config is wrong or your changing the wrong binding. WCF configs are a nightmare though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103650/discussion-between-eschneider-and-holt).

Comment: In that mindset...the server is sending data to the client.  So you are thinking there is something wrong with my client (meaning the Web.config file within the RateService project)?

Comment: My main issue was my lack of understanding what the 'client' was while debugging a WCF service via WCFStorm.  Once I got that Storm itself was the client...I just needed to setup the correct message sizes within Storm and I was all set.  Thanks for the help @eschneider.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with eschneider. You need to change the setting under your client's  (RateService project) MAIN Web.config file. Right click it and select Edit WCF Configuration. In the pop-up window under Configuration panel select Bindings > *YourDefinedBinding* (e.g. wsHttpBinding). Then change the MaxReceivedMessageSize to 2147483647. I hope this can help you.

Comment: The config file that I am showing within my original question is the RateService Web.Config.  So I have already set `MaxReceivedMessageSize` there.

Comment: Since I am hosting this service locally via IIS, it seems like IIS is not keeping the binding settings from the WebConfig within the RateService.

Comment: Does your client consume WCF service through Service Reference? If so, have you manually updated Service Reference on client side so that all changes take effect? (Right-click the service reference you created and then click Update Service Reference.)